# Setting JAVA_HOME on OSX 10.8

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion

I am on OSX 10.8

when I say which `javac` it will print out this:

```
/usr/bin/javac
```

I Googled about setting `JAVA_HOME` and I see people saying I should do this: ( I want Java 6.0 instead of 7 too )

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

so is that ALL I need to do?  I see some places say then I should also set the PATH ?

Comment: You mean you have Java 7 in your machine but you want to force javac to use Java 6?

Comment: @Jean! that's actually the link I copy pasted the export java_home from it and have more questions based on that I asked here.

Comment: I understand. On the duplicate, **onpduo** says it works. So, I don't understand your question. Did you test to see if it worked? Wether or not is all you need to do? I mean, where did you put `export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6'`? In your ~/.bash_profile? If so, you may need to quit the terminal and launch it again.